# Can we match a localfield of a MongoDB document with some other localfield of same document?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I am having an aggregate query

> { $match: {  'projects.status.status':
>   'Approved'   ,   'projects.status.college_id': '$collegeDetail._id' }},

within which I am having this Match Query , where first part of the match query return correct document if latter part is removed.

**$collegeDetail._id** Is unable to match the correct element. Though the id in this field is same and of same data type as that of (**projects.status.college_id**)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: This question is not same as the one you mentioned @Neil Lunn .
This match query is in aggregate part of the query. We cant use $where in aggregate's match.

Comment: There's other solutions there than using `$where`. Look further and scroll down. You want `$redact` or even `$expr` if your MongoDB supports the latter. It certainly supports the former.

Comment: Thanks dude. My local Version is 3.4. So $expr didnt worked.  And neither $cmp could compare two objectids . But somehow $eq did. :)